# jQuery submit() after preventDefault() not submiting form properly

Tags: jquery, forms, preventdefault

I've got a form which submits values to paypal ...

before submitting to paypal i wanted to programmatically check the variables and save them to database first

To do this, I have an on(submit) code that intercepts the default form action, and submits the variables to my script first for pre-processing..

then once OK, i then invoke the submit function for the form..

The result = the form is posting BLANK/ZERO variables

```
cleared_to_submit = 0;
$("#my_form").on("submit", function(e){


    if(cleared_to_submit){
        cleared_to_submit = 0;
        return;
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
        postvars = $(this).serializeArray();
        $(this).find(":input").prop("disabled",true);


        url = "?act=pay_now&";
        $.post( url, postvars ,function(data){
            var stat = data.stat;

            if(stat == 'ok'){
                cleared_to_submit = 1;
                $("#my_form").submit(); //resubmit form

            }else if( stat == 'input_error'){

                showAlert(statMsg, "danger");

                $("#my_form").find(":input").prop("disabled",false);

            }else{ // ERROR
                $("#my_form").find(":input").prop("disabled",false);
                showAlert("Error:" + statMsg, "error");

            }
        });
    }




});
```

Is this an expected side effect?

Comment: `cleared_to_submit` always 0

Comment: newp, it's set to 1 right before submit is called (root variable)
and plus i know it works cause the page actually goes to the paypal page but w/o variables.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the flag `cleared_to_submit` to go around the `e.preventDefault()`, try using `$(this).unbind("submit").submit();` once you've done what you need to do in this `$("#my_form").on("submit", function(e){` function.

So basically what I'm trying to say is: once you've validated your form in the `.submit()` event, you can use this code to submit the form without calling the `.submit()` event you've bound.

For example:

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      
    //...validation here
    if(stat == 'ok'){
        $(this).unbind("submit").submit(); // this line will not trigger the same submit event
    }
    //...
});
```

I'm not certain that this will solve your problem, but it can give you an idea of how to validate your forms easier.

Comment: tnx for the idea mate.. but it's still the same effect.. programatically calling submit after the preventDefault has been called seems to mess up the posting of the variables :(

Comment: if you try to console.log($(this).serializeArray()) what is printed?

Comment: ok so i called console.log($(this).serializeArray()); on both the conditions.. at the first run (before the post) the variables are there.. but on the 2nd run , as expected, console.log return nothing .. 

strange really.

Comment: try using just .serialize() just to see if it passes anything

Comment: i actually redirected the form action to my own script that will echo back all the $_POST and $_GET variables to be super sure.. and as expected, the darn thing received nothing...

Comment: from the api at jquery they passed the vars like $.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize()); Also, I have always just used .serialize();

Comment: for my situation, it doesn't matter how you call serialize mate.. all has the same issue.. and remember, my problem is not when i am posting via JQUERY.. I get all vars no problem.. My issue is when i trigger the form to submit "regularly" .. the form seems to lose variables, or references to the input fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57687/discussion-between-eg-dac-and-brownchild).

Answer (score 1):

It's because I disabled the form `input` fields

```
$(this).find(":input").prop("disabled",true);
```

and didn't re-enable them before calling `submit()` apparently, if form input fields are disabled, so are their variables.

Answer (score 0):

try to put `$(this).find(":input").prop("disabled",true);` after calling `$.post` method, POST method variable will empty if the input form being disabled